# Ubuntu 14.04 unity shows wrong battery status

Tags: 14.04, unity, laptop, power-management, battery

I am using ASUS laptop and the model is X555-50. I have ubuntu 14.04 installed with unity desktop.

It used to show the correct battery status earlier. But suddenly it is not displaying the correct battery status

1. It would not show the battery remaining
2. It would not show the charging icon even when I plug-in the cable

This is causing trouble as I don't know when my laptop is running out of battery

I have windows 10 as a dual boot. The battery indicator works fine on windows 10.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

**1.It would not show the battery remaining**

I suggest you to use Xfce desktop environment with xfce-power-manager to make sure your battery is fine or not . If in Xfce you get same problem , i think there something wrong your machine or your battery .

**2.It would not show the charging icon even when I plug-in the cable**

If the charging icon is not show up when you plug-in the cable , i think there are problem with your icon theme.Try other icon theme pack like Faenza to make sure fine your battery .

Answer (score 0):

Check settings in System settings > Power management. You can change there when to show battery: make sure Never is not the chosen one.